# How can I use will_paginate on a collection of partials away from an index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, partials

I currently have a users page which displays all the reviews that user has written. Each review is displayed as a partial (named _profile) and they are all shown on a page of an accordian. How can I add pagination to these review partials?

**users show page**

```
<div class="profile_reviews_container">
  <div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Reviews written</a></h3>
    <div class="profile_reviews_cont">
      <% @user.reviews.each do |review| %>
        <%= render "reviews/profile", :profile => review %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <h3><a href="#">Favourites</a></h3>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which controller do I add the .paginate call to and will the view contain `<%= will_paginate @reviews %>` or `<%= will_paginate @profiles %>`?

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would paginate the Reviews in the Users#show action.  Something like:

```
@reviews = @user.reviews.paginate page: params[:page]
```

And then call:

```
<%= will_paginate @reviews %>
```

in the view.

I would also change the name of the partial (or create a new one) to `reviews/_review` so you can just call:

```
<%= render @reviews %>
```

But that's me.

Comment: thanks for the answer, its sort of working although the partials aren't being split across the pagination pages, so theres the correct number of pages for the amount of records but each page displays all the records (not 5 as I set in the controller). The reason for the _profile partial is because I already have a _review partial displaying elsewhere and this just has differant info being displayed and a differant style attached.

Comment: Had to also change the line <% @user.reviews.each do |review| %> to <% @reviews.each do |review| %>, now it works thanks for the help.